# Can we change Windows TaskBar padding?

Tags: windows, taskbar

[image]

I had been using 125% DPI but the font size on legacy Win32 dialogue boxes/menu was too small, so I changed it 150%. Now the legacy Win32 font is legible, but the Task Bar (and other OS elements like the title bar) is too big. As you see, it has A LOT of unnecessary padding. This is a laptop so vertical space is very limited; it seems stupid to waste the space for padding like this. I suspect that Windows has no ability adjust the padding size, but I am asking if there is a way, just in case.

Comment: Do you want only the icon to be shown?

Comment: There is a registry setting for padding, **depending on Windows version**.